# How can I vertically align buttons in grid items in a grid layout without using padding or margin?

Tags: css, css-grid

[image: Snippet of my design]

How can I have all 3 buttons(in different grid items in a grid layout) in the same line without using padding or margin?

Comment: Hi. I assume you are using padding for the card it self, so top right bottom left?